# Orange Pi 5 CAN-bus issues

Tags: can, linux

The bus-topology is like this. The CAN-bus has termination resistor at the inverter and in the Waveshare USB/CAN dongle.

```
┌─────────┐          ┌─────────┐          ┌─────────┐
│Waveshare│          │OPi5 Plus│          │         │
│ USB/CAN │◀────────▶│  can1   │◀────────▶│Inverter │
│         │          │         │          │         │
└─────────┘          └─────────┘          └─────────┘
```

**Bus properties**
The bus-speed is dictated by the inverter, 250 kbit/s.

`can1` is configured like this

```
# ip -d link show dev can1
5: can1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 1 
          bitrate 250000 sample-point 0.871 
          tq 30 prop-seg 57 phase-seg1 57 phase-seg2 17 sjw 1
          rockchip_canfd: tseg1 1..128 tseg2 1..128 sjw 1..128 brp 1..256 brp-inc 2
          clock 198000000 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Commands used to bring up `can1` are

```
ip link set can1 type can bitrate 250000
ip link set can1 up
```

i.e. all but bit-rate is kept at default values. `listen-only` mode is verified to be `off`.

**What works**

Receiving CAN-frames works as expected

```
# candump can1
  can1  1801F150   [8]  08 04 00 00 00 00 F0 93
  can1  1801F150   [8]  09 04 00 00 00 00 F1 42
```

Sending/receiving frames when `can1` is put into loopback mode.

**What doesn't work**

Sending frames over the CAN bus.

Verification that transmission fails is done both by sniffing the CAN-bus with the Waveshare USB/CAN dongle and by monitoring Linux counters.

The TX queue for `can1` fills up quite fast, for example by using `cangen`

```
# cangen can1
write: No buffer space available
```

The error is displayed after 2 seconds, i.e. after 10 messages is queued for transmission.

```
# ip -s -d link show dev can1
5: can1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 1 
          bitrate 250000 sample-point 0.871 
          tq 30 prop-seg 57 phase-seg1 57 phase-seg2 17 sjw 1
          rockchip_canfd: tseg1 1..128 tseg2 1..128 sjw 1..128 brp 1..256 brp-inc 2
          clock 198000000 
          re-started bus-errors arbit-lost error-warn error-pass bus-off
          12         0          0          17         18         12        numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
    RX:  bytes packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
      14545088 1818136      0       0       0       0 
    TX:  bytes packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
             0       0      0      17       0       0
```

After some time elapses, `error-warn` counter and `error-pass` will be incremented by 1 and `dropped` is incremented by 1 and all queued packets seems to be dropped.

One thing I noticed is that the interrupt counter and `RX-packets` counter is incremented as expected after the interface is brought down and then up. But the both those counters are incremented *very* fast, >1000 times per second, after calling `cansend` and packets are queued for transmission.

This behaviour persists for some time, then goes back to normal. Nothing seems to be received while in this "increasing counters very fast" state.

Also tested with `can0` interface on the RPi5 Plus, same behaviour.

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong? It's frustrating that the RX path works as expected, but not the TX one.

Edit: found [this one](https://www.electronicshub.org/arduino-mcp2515-can-bus-tutorial/), CAN support for Arduino.

[image]

Orange Pi 5 labels the CAN-pins `CAN1_RX_M0` and `CAN1_TX_M0`. TX/RX is also used in the picture above from the control-chip, but CAN uses differential pairs which are labelled `CANH` and `CANL` above.

**Answer**

Found the answer to my own question, the two CAN-ports on the Orange Pi 5 Plus is *only* the controller. One has to add an external transceiver-chip!

Kind of annoying that reception just worked "good enough" when adding the OPi5 to an existing CAN-bus...

Comment: "tq 30 prop-seg 57 phase-seg1 57 phase-seg2 17 sjw 1" What's this nonsense suppose to mean? The CAN standard allows a maximum of 25 tq and in any case the total tq ought the be the sum of 1=sync bit + the propagation segment + phase seg1 + phase seg 2. 1 + 57 + 57 + 17 is not 30.

Comment: "incremented very fast, >1000 times per second" Obviously, since a CAN frame typically takes less than 1ms to transmit. If you get an error per CAN frame, then the counters will quickly hit 128 and 256 leading to error passive and then bus off.

Comment: And for future trouble-shooting here's a CAN beginner problems FAQ: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)